# React navigation With Deep Linking - Issue Accessing Child Action and Params

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to make Deep Linking work with React Navigation. My flow is:

- User clicks on Deep Link
- App opens
- In my App Navigator, I check if user has come via a Deep Link

I do following:

```
const App = createSwitchNavigator({
  MyDrawerNavigator: MyDrawerNavigator,
  AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
  Auth: AuthStack,
  Main: MainTabNavigator,
  Profile: ProfileNavigator,
  ActivityListNav: {screen: ActivityListNavigator,
                  path: 'activity'}, 
},{
  initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
})

const previousGetActionForPathAndParams = App.router.getActionForPathAndParams;

Object.assign(App.router, {
  getActionForPathAndParams(path, params) {
    //alert('path : ' + path + ' params : ' + params);
    const isAuthLink = path.startsWith('activity');
    //alert('isAuthLink : ' + isAuthLink);
    if (isAuthLink) {
      return NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: 'AuthLoading',
        params: { ...params, path },
      });
    }
    return previousGetActionForPathAndParams(path, params);
  },
});

const XYZApp = createAppContainer(App);

const prefix = 'https://XYZApp.com/referral/';

export default MainApp = () => <XYZApp uriPrefix={prefix} />;
```

Control is successfully passed to AuthLoading component. Here this is what I'm doing:

```
const params = this.props.navigation.state.params;

let action;

if (params && params.path) {
      const routeParams = params;
      const routeName = params.path;
      action = NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: routeName, params: routeParams });
    }

    if (!userToken){
      this.fetchUserData();
    }else{
      this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName:'PhoneAuth',
        action,
      }))
      this.props.navigation.navigate('PhoneAuth')
}
```

This moves the control successfully to PhoneAuth component. Now here, based on what was passed in 'action', I need to navigate further. But I am not able to figure out how to extract values from 'action.  I've tried following:

```
const params = this.props.navigation.state.params;
const routeName = this.props.navigation.state.routeName;
const { navigation } = this.props;
const referrer = navigation.getParam('refereeName', 'NO-ID');
const childState = PhoneAuth.router.getStateForAction();

if (params && routeName){
 return this.props.navigation.navigate(routeName, params);
}
```

But here, I'm getting params as undefined and routeName as PhoneAuth instead of what was passed from Deep Link.

Comment: Why do you move the same screen twice?

Comment: I'm not moving it twice. From AppNavigator->AuthLoading->PhoneAuth->WhateverIsInDeepLink

Comment: The conditional statement of the code has an order to move the screen twice.